# What does Emacs' learning curve (actually) look like?

Tags: emacs

What does Emacs' learning curve (actually) look like?

Some time ago, someone gave a graph showing how learning curves look different for different editors:

[image: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2004/11/17/code-editor-learning-curves.aspx]

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2004/11/17/code-editor-learning-curves.aspx

Assuming the horizontal axes is the experience with the tool, and vertical axes the retained information, what I can't understand about the above graph is how can the curve for Emacs curve backward as your experience should always increase?!

Comment: Of course not... it's a joke/punchline. (And this is OT). However, since emacs is really just elisp with an editor slapped on top... there is never an end to how "intimate" one can get with it.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke

Comment: No, I did get it that it's meant to be humorous.  But the drawing did not make sense.  If I were the cartoonist, I probably will draw a wavy line slightly sloped upwards.

Comment: @Problemania ...and it would not have been funny. Emacs is relatively easy to get started with as it's "like notepad" or "pico" and the standard arrow key bindings work, etc (and emacs supports GUIs with full menus now)... but it's an "open" tool. Use as many modes, keybindings, macros, custom scripts, etc, as desired. (And if the ones in the box aren't good enough, write your own or steal someone else's .el file.)

Comment: To me, the Emacs curve was funny at first but then did not make sense, and caused me think how the learning curve for Emacs should actually look like, at least for myself.   I've been using Emacs for several years.

Comment: @Problemania *sigh* I have a feeling I would not "get" your take on political cartoons...

Comment: Let me try some other day.  True humor always makes sense at end.

Comment: That graph is mathematically wrong

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a good joke, with some definite truth to it.

I always assumed the author meant it as an indication that the more you learn about Emacs, the more possibilities for further learning open up to you. Hence the infinite spiral.

Or to put it another way, the more you know, the more you realise what you don't know :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case it looks like:

```
|
|
|-___________
```

I fired up emacs by mistake and could not figure out how to 
exit, I ended up logging in from another terminal and killing the process.

This was enough to convince me that vi was not so bad after all.

Comment: It somewhat resembles my first experience with vim.

Comment: @Problemania -- How to learn VI: Place left hand in door jamb then slam door, repeat for right hand. Now all your fingers are in the correct position!

Comment: To exit, hit `C-g C-g C-g C-x C-c n n ... n yes RET`.

Comment: To exit vim, type `q : : q : q`.